# Show preloader only once without showing body content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a preloader on my page that should be shown only when you first enter a site. It almost works, but when I enter my site for the first time I see the content of the site for 0.5 and only then my preloader. But I don't want to see the content instantly. I want to see it only when my preloader fades out. How can I do it?

parents div needs to be a flexbox.

```html
<div id="over">
    <img src="sourse.jpg" class="pic">
</div>
```

```css
#over {
display: none;
z-index: 10000000000;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: black;
}

.pic{
margin: auto;
}
```

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null){
  $("#over").css("display", "flex");
  $("#over").delay(3500).fadeOut(1800);
  $(".pic").delay(2500).fadeOut(2300);
  sessionStorage.setItem('dontLoad', 'true');
}
```

Comment: When are you loading this JS? If it is after your content and not the first thing loaded, you will always see that HTML first.

Comment: Add `style='display:none` to your main content (not the #over).  What your seeing is the standard *fouc* which you get because your js runs after everything has loaded

Comment: There is no difference where I load it. I tried a lot of options but I always see my content first:(

Comment: For better result I would suggest `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none` for you main content. So, the layout can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a callback after the preloader animation is complete, and then show the content.
In my opinion if you need the parent div to be a flexbox, you could try using `visibility:hidden;` to hide the content instead set it to `display:none;`.

**CSS**

```
#over {
display: flex;
visibility:hidden;
z-index: 10000000000;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background-color: black;
}
```

**JS**

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null){

  $(".pic").delay(2500).fadeOut(2300, function(){
    $( "#over" ).animate({
      visibility: visible
   }, 3500);
  });
  sessionStorage.setItem('dontLoad', 'true');
}
```